# Problems loading content from MySQL into CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ckeditor

I would like to load the content of the database (HTML) into a  with CKEditor. Unfortunately I can't get any further.
Thanks for your help!
This is my code

```
HTML:
<textarea  rows="3" id="beschreibung_bearbeiten" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $programme['beschreibung']; ?>"><!-- VALUE HERE --></textarea>

SCRIPT
 <script>

                CKEDITOR.replace( 'beschreibung_neu' );
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'beschreibung_bearbeiten' );


  </script> 
$('#modal_programm_bearbeiten').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var id = button.data('id');
          $("#hidden_id").val(id);


          $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $syspath; ?>pages/ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                onsubmit: "'editor.post();'",

                data: { ACTION : "programmdaten_holen", ID : id },

                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#name_bearbeiten").val(data.name);
                    $("#beschreibung_bearbeiten").val(data.beschreibung);
                    $("#notiz_bearbeiten").val(data.notiz);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    alert(error + " Fehler beim-- Holen der Datensätze");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify what  the actual issue is that you need help with. Is it the PHP or the CKEDITOR or some other problem? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Hello, I need help to show the content from the database in the <textarea>. The editor is loaded correctly, unfortunately only without content. I don't see an error message. The previous content from the database is simply not loaded as "value". The rest works. I think the error is in php / script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can somebody help me